# Where can I register a domain and pay with bitcoins?

Tags: services, websites, payment, domain-registering

Where can I register a domain name and pay with bitcoins?

(The question is about usual domain names, not .bit maintained by the namecoin network.)

Comment: I've closed this because it is a [Shopping List question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/158810/232061): These type of questions can never have a definitive answer, answers outdate quickly, and as shown yesterday, they tend to attract spam. Questions like this work better on other platforms where content visibility is nearer the time of posting, while Stackexchange tries to form a question and answer collection to last.

Answer (score 11):

Note that all services need to be checked by you somehow to decide whether you can trust them!

There is a list of such services at https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Trade#Domain_Name_and_DNS_Hosting; for example:

- http://www.domains4bitcoins.com (com, net, org, co, co.uk, in, biz, us, eu, mobi, asia, name, tel, co.in, tv, me, info, ws, bz, cc, org.uk, me.uk, net.in, org.in, ind.in, firm.in, gen.in, mn, us.com, eu.com, uk.com, uk.net, gb.com, gb.net, de.com, cn.com, qc.com, kr.com, ae.org, br.com, hu.com, jpn.com, no.com, ru.com, sa.com, se.com, se.net, uy.com, za.com, gr.com, co.nz, net.nz, org.nz, com.co, net.co, nom.co, ca, de, es, com.au, net.au, xxx)
- http://bitdomain.biz (biz, com, com, org, info, us, eu, in, mobi, asia, name, tel, tv, me, ws, bz, cc, mn, ca, de, es, com.au, net.au, xxx)
- http://www.cinfu.com/domains/ (com, net, org, biz, info, eu, in, us, de, ru, es, asia, bz, ca, cc, co, mn, mobi, name, me, tel, tv, xxx, *.uk, ws, la, tw, cn, ac, io, sh, nu, be, tc, vg, ms, gs, jp, at, am and more 2nd level domain)
- http://www.exoware.net/domainregistration.xhtml (com, eu, me, org, me.uk, de, es, co.uk, net, name, info, org.uk, cc, tel, ca, biz, tv, co)
- https://www.kalyhost.com/domain.html (many different top-level domains
- https://clients.microtronix-tech.com/domainchecker.php (not so many top-level domains)
- https://secure.orangewebsite.com/cart.php?a=add&domain=register (not so many top-level domains)
- http://www.privacyshark.com/ (anonymous, but not clear which top-level domains are offred)
- http://www.frankdomains.com/btc (all top-level domains and all European TLDs e.g. .com, .xxx, [.travel](http://www.frankdomains.com/why-register-.travel-domain/), .at (Austria) through to .com.ua (Ukraine) and all countries inbetween Also [all New gTLDs](http://www.frankdomains.com/register-new-gtlds/) as they come online)
- https://www.namecheap.com/support/payment-options/bitcoin.aspx (Namecheap: Many TLD's)
- ...

More offers:

- https://www.domenburg.com (Instant registration after 1 btc confirmation, 500+ TLDs: ru, com, net, org, co, pro, in, biz, us, eu, mobi, asia, name, tel, co.in, tv, me, info, ws, bz, cc, ca, de, es, ...)

Answer (score 7):

The only three ICANN accredited registrars who accept bitcoin presently are No-IP, easyDNS and Namecheap.

https://www.noip.com/bitcoin

http://blog2.easydns.org/2013/04/16/we-now-accept-bitcoin-as-a-payment-method/

https://www.namecheap.com/support/payment-options/bitcoin.aspx

Comment: could you provide some source for your affirmation: "The only three ICANN accredited registrars who accept bitcoin presently are "?

Answer (score 2):

I just found a new provider that accept bitcoins, http://www.bitronictech.net/

They accept bitcoin for domain registration and all of their other services.

They have an article about their Bitcoin Gateway here: http://www.bitronictech.net/announcements/25/Buy-Domain-Names-with-Bitcoins.html

Answer (score 2):

[***Frank Domains***](http://www.frankdomains.com/pay-for-domains-with-bitcoins/) offers domain registration via Bitcoin payments. They have a [Bitcoin version](http://www.frankdomains.com/btc/) of their entire site.

As well as anonymity, they also provide extra domain security in the form of [*Domainsafe*](http://www.frankdomains.com/keep-your-domain-safe/), a Bank-style login security by means of physical key fob.

Frank Domains also provide one of the fastest domain search engines that i have come across, which can provide all the results in Bitcoin amounts.

Answer (score 1):

I always use http://www.domains4bitcoins.com they take Bitcoin and have free privacy protection and DNS.

(com     net     org
 co  co.uk   in
 biz     us  eu
 mobi    asia    name
 tel     co.in   tv
 me  info    ws
 bz  cc  org.uk
 me.uk   net.in  org.in
 ind.in  firm.in gen.in
 mn  us.com  eu.com
 uk.com  uk.net  gb.com
 gb.net  de.com  cn.com
 qc.com  kr.com  ae.org
 br.com  hu.com  jpn.com
 no.com  ru.com  sa.com
 se.com  se.net  uy.com
 za.com  gr.com  co.nz
 net.nz  org.nz  com.co
 net.co  nom.co  ca
 de  es  com.au
 net.au  xxx)