# Where can I register a .RU domain and pay with bitcoins?

Tags: services, payment, domain-registering

Where can I register a .RU domain and pay with bitcoins?

(There are [several services offering the registration of "international" domains](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/3229/817) and accepting bitcoin payments, but what about .RU domain?)

Comment: Your recent posts seem to some people like spam / rep-whoring. http://meta.bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/253/what-is-the-limit-of-self-answering

Comment: @ripper: No, this is a specific question, and it costed me substantial effort to find the anser to this specific question: most of the known services do not offer .RU registration. So I had to check them one by one, find for each one the list of domains that are available, and look for .RU there. By posting this question and answer, I save the time and work of other people with the same need as mine.

Comment: You can edit the answer to the other generic question to pinpoint the RU domains ... essentially the two questions are so alike, they should just be one question.

Comment: @ripper234: no, this won't be a usable solution, because it would just dump the huge amount of information into the answer which a person looking just for .RU domain registration will have to look through, and this won't save the effort for him/her.

Answer (score 2):

There is a list of domain registration services at https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Trade#Domain_Name_and_DNS_Hosting. Among them, I could find .RU registration only at:

- http://www.cinfu.com/domains/ ($9.17/year)
- https://www.kalyhost.com/domain.html (for 18 EURO a year = 4.45BTC)
- ???

Answer (score 2):

[***Frank Domains***](http://www.frankdomains.com/pay-for-domains-with-bitcoins/) has entirely integrated its payment system with Bitcoins. They sell all TLD's and also a substantial number of ccTLD's, including .ru (http://www.frankdomains.com/.ru).

Its also relatively cheap for only 1.49BTC

There are other alternatives, but I prefer Frank Domains due to their extra security options.