# Anonymous Domain Registrations

Tags: domain-registering

Can anyone recommend a domain registrar which will both accept BTC and allow anonymous registrations?

I'm aware of this list:

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Trade#Domain_Name_and_DNS_Hosting

But was looking for recommendations as much as information.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic.

Comment: Quoting the tour page "Don't ask about [...] site, tool, library, or software recommendations". But it is an interesting question nevertheless, in my view and the answers are rather productive.

Answer (score 3):

I use [IT Itch](https://ititch.com/). They allow both anonymous domain registration and bitcoin payments. I also use them for my VPS web hosting and I find them pretty fantastic.

But be aware that some domain names can't be purchased anonymously. For instance, some domain registries require things like tax numbers or proof of citizenship, so make sure you choose a domain that supports anonymity (like .com, .net).

Comment: I think something went very wrong with them: "We have closed down
Unfortunately we have closed down and can no longer process new orders, renew existing services or provide support assistance.

Existing customers have until 19 December 2020 to transfer domains and migrate hosting services to new providers. After that time the website will go offline. Please ask your new provider if you need assistance with domain transfers or web hosting migrations."

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in a highly anonymous decentralised domain registration, then the [Namecoin project](http://dot-bit.org/Main_Page) is for you. It allows you to register .bit domains using an alt-coin similar to Bitcoin. However, you should be aware that access to those domains was hard without proper plugins the last time I checked.

Comment: Yes, it's a fascinating project, but until it is accessible in a vanilla browser it's not for me.

Answer (score 1):

@ThePiachu - I agree, the Dot-BIT project is very anonymous...if you want to register a .bit domain that is  (only .bit is available from the project so far). The problem with .bit domains is that the system is still very much in it's infancy and so hasn't developed to a point where it is as easily accessed as other "ICANN" domains.

In regards to the question, most registrars will require a certain level of identification when registering a domain (ICANN rules and regs). I know of a lot of registrars which only require a name, email address and physical address. I know, thats a lot of info if you are trying to remain anonymous, but paying by Bitcoin removes the vital registration check that matches the bank details with the other reg. info.

I'm **NOT** saying that you should lie, because there is a level of trust between registrars and their customers, which would be a shame to see disappear. Also fake info can lead to you losing the domain anyway. But the use of Bitcoin in itself will provide a certain level of anonymity.

If you request whois privacy, the regristrar will ensure that your details aren't available to the public, but they (and ICANN) will still have your details in their files.

As for complete anonymity, I'm unaware of any registrar offering that legally. It would have to be a decentralised domain system, one that wasn't regulated by ICANN, like Dot-BIT...

A really good list of Bitcoin-using registars can be found on this site at [Where can I register a domain and pay with bitcoins?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3229/where-can-i-register-a-domain-and-pay-with-bitcoins/7168#7168)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean with anonymous domain registration with a WhoisGuard, 
then you can check [superbithost](http://www.superbithost.com/).
They offer this as a free option in 90% of the domains. You can get there offshore hosting to...

Comment: Nice not seen them before. And they are not on the bitcoin wiki.

Answer (score 0):

namecheap.com accepts bitcoin and free domain info block (12 months) but not sure about the anonymity, maybe with a bitcoin purchase.

Answer (score 0):

I use bargainhost.co.uk for anonymous domain registrations, Bargainhost also accept bitcoin for payments.

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad to say that bargainhost.co.uk both accept BTC and allow anonymous registrations,so thats how i'll be paying from now

Answer (score 0):

you can register domain names with bitcoin and whois protection at https://monovm.com/domain/

Answer (score -1):

I work at a domain registration company who are about to offer anonymity with bitcoin funded domain registration.

We have been accepting Bitcoin for almost a year. We are about to set up this new service that will allow our customers to register domains using Bitcoin and remain anonymous to ICANN, Whois databases and the general public.

We are currently in the pre-alpha stage of developing the service, but will soon be shipping it out. In terms of answering your question, our service will allow you to remain anonymous online because we will complete the compulsory ICANN-mandated registration form with our own information. To all intents and purposes, we will be your domain trustee.

Of course you will be in complete control of the domain, and we will sign a contract assuring you of your ownership. But any information which you give to us will not be stored publicly and will be treated with absolute confidentiality.

I do not know of any other registrar currently who offers this service, but I'm sure someone will be able to point you in the direction of some others. We will announce the release of the service on our [website](http://www.frankdomains.com/pay-for-domains-with-bitcoins/), keep an eye out for when we go live.